# How to Solve setHttpPlugin.requestDidStart(...).willSendResponse is not a function in Test Case?

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs, testcase

I have this below code in hello.js file and I wrote test case for it but it's throwing error that setHttpPlugin.requestDidStart(...).willSendResponse is not a function, so anybody know about it how to solve it?

**hello.js**

```
const setHttpPlugin = {
  async requestDidStart(){
    return {
      async willSendResponse( { response } ){
        if( response?.errors?.[0]?.extensions?.code === 'TIMEOUT_ERROR' ){
          // eslint-disable-next-line no-param-reassign
          response.http.status = 504;
        }
        response?.errors?.forEach( ( error )=>{
          logError( `Error Occurred in WillSendResponse: `, error );
        } )
        if (!isEmpty(response?.errors)) {
          delete response?.errors // eslint-disable-line no-param-reassign
        }
      }
    };
  }
};
exports.setHttpPlugin = setHttpPlugin;
```

**hello.test.js**

```
describe( 'setHttpPlugin', () => {

  it('should set response status 504 when extensions code is present', async () => {
    const mockResponse = {
      errors: [
        {
          extensions: {
            code: 'TIMEOUT_ERROR'
          }
        }
      ],
      http: {
        status: 200
      }
    }

    await setHttpPlugin.requestDidStart().willSendResponse({ response: mockResponse });
    expect( mockResponse.http.status ).toBe( 504 );
  });
} );
```

I tried using export setHttpPlugin object but still getting error.